# How to utilize more of my CPUs on my EC2 instance?

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, cpu, cpu-usage

Hello I'm quite new with EC2 instances but i want my EC2 ubuntu server to be as powerful as possible. That is why I've chosen the t2.2xlarge instance with 8 CPUs and 32GiB in memory.
However, I feel like the performance is the same as compared to the "free tier" version I used to run my python script on.
When I look at the CPU usage on my machine, it says only 8%.

How can I utilize much more of my CPUs?

In my script, I essentially perform the following. By doing this, it should utilize one CPU per function call. However, when I check the CPU usage again. It shows that only 8% of the CPU is used whereas each CPU should be dedicated to one function task??

```
import multiprocessing as mp

# each process will use each CPU
pool = mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count())
results=[]

for ii in range(0, len(tmpDF_forPeerGroup)):
    pool.apply_async(construct_each_company, args=(tmpDF_forPeerGroup, ii), callback=collect_result)

pool.close()
# postpones the execution of next line of code until all processes in the queue are done.
pool.join() 

# Step 5: Sort results [OPTIONAL]
results.sort(key=lambda x: x[0])
finalListForCompanies = [r for (ii, r) in results]
```

Comment: Maybe you should paralelize your python code

Comment: any recommendations on which tools to use?

Comment: Python 3 has a built in multiprocessing package `multiprocessing` https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=process

Comment: Hello Matthew, I've updated my code to include multiprocessing but still find the same issue. Only 8% of my CPU capacity is used. Any idea why? Maybe because it's waiting for all 8 processes to finish before carrying on the next 8 ones??

Comment: Would you have any ideas ?

Comment: Have you tryied with Joblib and Parallel?

Comment: @nacho no i didn't. Does that mean that my code above doesn't work using all of the CPUs? Why is joblib and Parallel better?

Comment: No, i don't say anything is better. I have always used Joblib and it works ok for me. I don't know how to do it with multiprocessing but i think your code looks ok, so i don't know where can be the problem

Comment: What does your construct_each_company function do?

Comment: @nacho It's basically reading 4 different tables from SQL queries and aggreagting them.

Comment: Any ideas why it's only using 8% of my CPU resources?